# Joomla scrolling text module

Tags: html, joomla, joomla2.5

Currently developing site in Joomla 2.5, finding a way to add a module that scrolls news automatically. After much search I am unable to develop a scrolling news module from the scratch.

I have developed in plain JavaScript and html but completely unaware as how to do in my Joomla website.

Comment: Am just wondering, why would you want to do it from scratch?

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot of joomla scrolling module available.you can check and use the module which is fulfilling your requirement.Here is the complete list of these modules http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/news-display/articles-display/news-tickers-a-scrollers and i have used this module serval times and its works well for me everytime.http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/news-display/articles-display/news-tickers-a-scrollers/11827

Comment: Yes the extensions are cool. Made my work damn easy!!. Its just what I expected.. Thanks

Comment: hi, i found a pause scroll plugin for displaying my latest news articles. I have installed as a plugin in my extensions manager but i have no knowledge of using a plugin. Documentation provided also confuses me. This is the plugin that i downloaded .. http://www.kksou.com/php-gtk2/Joomla/Pausing-up-down-Scroller-module.php. Please help .

Comment: Ita a module not plugin....you check it in module manager and assign a postition of use it,

Comment: You are correct it is a module, but i downloaded only the plugin version of the scroll. To make it work we need to have enabled both the module and plugin version. Now it works !!!

Comment: hi i m not sure where to do this upvote.. anyway i have yet another doubt, i need to attach anchor tag to this module name.. so when clicked on the header of the module it leads to complete list of items that is scrolling .. Please help..

Comment: You can accept the answer by clicking on right mark infront of myanswer and upvote the answer by clicking on up arrow. and for link you have to link from the module files